# Cannot redeclare function error

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare close() (previously declared in
>   E:\wamp1\wamp\www\sample.php:1) in  E:\wamp1\wamp\www\sample.php on
>   line 9

```
function close($tb,$lr) {
        echo '#close {
                '.$tb.':-2.5%;
                '.$lr.':-1.5%;
                position:absolute;
                cursor:pointer; 
        }';
    }
close($close_tb, $close_lr);
```

When I run this script it says cannot redeclare close()(previously decalred in line 1) in line 9.

Even on error the values associate with `$close_tb` and `$closr_lr` are passed to the css.
What wrong am doing here? am just calling the function in line 9. Any help?

Comment: Can you copy the exact error code you are receiving and paste it in a  blockquote within your question?

Comment: Something isn't right here, you've got something else (which isn't shown here) mucking with this. Working as expected: http://codepad.org/ca2Wf20r

Comment: And look for possible includes in your code, perhaps you're calling another close() function in another php script.

Comment: Can we see *all* the code please? (Your code works fine for me, other than `$close_tb` and `$close_lr` being undefined.) Is line 1 *really* line 1? If so, where's your opening `<?php`?

Comment: File could be included multiple times - have you checked for this possibility?

Answer (score 0):

This means you already have a function called `close()`.

Maybe you're including the same file twice or had a freak copypasta accident. Check your code for any double functions.

The fact that your script still works as expected likely means you have the exact same function twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your error code means that you are defining the function `close` twice. The code you have provided does not illustrate this, however, you must have either included the file more than once, or may have duplicated your code.

Go through your code and ensure you are not including the function definition more than once.